# How do I add a Touch Event in android App development?

Tags: android, touch

In my app
Table rows are there as I touch to any row I want to give some color to particular row which is selected.
The rest of the element should have the original color to it.

I have used onTouchlisterner but it's nt working as expected.

Comment: What does the code that is not working as expected look like?

Comment: set drawable xml  as row's background and have onclick event .... you can do it... follow this for creating xml http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=56

Comment: after touch to any row then it should highlight like origional bgcolor is white and after touch i want bgcolor should be grey or any other color.but i have done all coding but it is not doing what i want it should do..

Comment: Wt happen you did that or not.. accept the answer dude..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create rowbackground.xml in drawable for having two state for background image (normal and clicked state).

For that follow this link

http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=56

Then give it as background resource  for your rows you are creating.

Also you can have onclick listener for all rows ,just give tag or id as unique one for each row.